# org-babel - Use specific python path and command line option

Tags: org-babel

Since different python version installed on my system, how can I use specific python and option to run it?

For example,below test.py file will print hello output.

```
#!/opt/anaconda3/bin/python --myoptions
print("hello")
```

I want to get a equivalent by org-babel, maybe something like below:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results :cmd /opt/anaconda3/bin/python :option --myoptions
print("hello")
#+END_SRC
```

Do we have such option to config that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Org 9.2.3 function `org-babel-execute:python` contains following `let`-assignment:

```el
(org-babel-python-command
      (or (cdr (assq :python params))
          org-babel-python-command))
```

Therefore, the header argument you are looking for is (at least in that Org version):

`:python /opt/anaconda3/bin/python --myoptions`

Those lines have been introduced in Org at [commit e527e49c38](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/e527e49c38c9d54aadf7bdeaba68e89012b963cb).

Note, that those lines are [also part of the newest release on 2019-12-27, i.e., Org 9.3.1](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/release_9.3.1/lisp/ob-python.el#L75-L77).

Comment: Alternatively, the variable can be customized once and for all to the desired value. That way, you don't have to specify it for each code block.